# Payflow Pro .Net SDK (Payflow_dotNET.dll) missing CUSTREF option for Inquiry Transaction command

Tags: .net, paypal, payflowpro

I suspect its just missing from the Payflow_dotNET.dll library (I checked version 4.50) but wanted to see if anyone else noticed that you can't use the inquiry transaction command with CUSTREF. Their [SDK documentation](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_guide.pdf) references it on page 39.

I don't believe you can just use CUSTREF in place of the ORIGID parameter but maybe someone else has more experience with this than me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the samples installed with the SDK, they show how in DOInquiry.cs. It involves creating an invoice with that CustRef and passing it through.

```
// To use CUSTREF instead of PNREF you need to set the CustRef and include the INVOICE object in your
// request.  Since you will be using CUSTREF instead of PNREF, PNREF will be "" (null).
// Create a new Invoice data object with the Amount, Billing Address etc. details.
Invoice Inv = new Invoice();
Inv.CustRef = "A54321";
InquiryTransaction Trans = new InquiryTransaction("", User, Connection, Inv, PayflowUtility.RequestId);
```